# Requiring jQuery and lodash with browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, browserify, lodash

I love the idea of browserify, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around requiring 'global' variables, like jQuery and lodash.  I would expect:

```
// application.js
var $ = require('jquery')
var _ = require('lodash')
var a = require('./path/to/module/a.js')
```

To make `$` and `_` available to module a.  After all, that code is compiled, and `$` and `_` are defined first.  However I get an issue and the page won't load, saying that `$` and `_` are undefined.  Alright, I don't get it, but at the very least I would expect:

```
// a.js
var $ = require('jquery')
var _ = require('lodash')

var AClass = function() {
  console.log($, _)
}
module.exports = AClass
```

to run without issues.  However, I keep getting errors saying `$` and `_` are not defined, even though in both files the following code works:

```
var $ = require('jquery')
var _ = require('lodash')
console.log($, _)
```

Is there something wrong with my app beyond this, or is there something I'm fundamentally not understanding about browserify?

Comment: if you want to use jquery and lodash in `a`, you need to require jquery and lodash in the `a` module.

Comment: I have same issue, but I require lo-dash in same file, and before _.extend bla bla - lodash works, but I can't use lodash in function... code sample here - http://pastebin.com/YufmJiqF 
Do you solve the problem?

Comment: hmm, solve problem.
Just rename _ to 'lodash' and all works fine ;)

Answer (score 2):

we are using browserify (with gulp in our case) and we initialize globals like using thw window object. In this way you can also use them in your console if you have to do some tests.

```
window._ = require('lodash');
```

or, if you use ES6:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
window._ = _;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

With modern JavaScript, tools try to avoid global variables. If you look at the code in the browser, you'll probably see something like this:

```
(function() {
    var $ = require('jquery');
})();
```

Since `$` is wrapped in a function, it's no longer a global variable.

The correct way to fix this is to add the require in `a` as well. This isn't very expensive since `require()` will always return the same (cached) object for each requirement name.

The other option is to manually make the local variable global by using

```
window.$ = $;
```

inside of your first module. But this has several drawbacks:

- It will break if someone changes the order of modules
- If someone defines another global variable `window.$`, it might break

That's why it's best to use `require()` in every module.